# I can't implement an interface class for some static classes so what's the alternative?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a family of maths algorithms that all should follow same structures, so I wanted each of these classes to implement a common interface class. But the compiler says it's not possible for static class.

So what should I do:

- Make static non static
- Or use Inheritance
- Or better alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by 'following the same structure'? Are the algorithms interchangeable in some way: specializations for different data types, or optimized for different problem ranges? Or do you just want things to be neat? If the latter, interface implementation or inheritance is overkill.

Comment: I mean same methods but different formulas inside. These methods will be created by third parties and called by us that's why I need some contracts to be enforced.

Comment: Why should the methods be static then? Obviously that’s not the case.

Comment: because it's like .NET static Math library I don't need several instances.

Comment: But I have several such libraries which all have the same method definitions but different implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using an interface or an abstract base class along with a factory which will return the proper algorithm implementation based on some input. By making those classes implement an interface you will also bring weaker coupling between the consumers of those methods and the algorithms and you will also benefit from the possibility of unit testing in isolation the different parts of your application.

---

UPDATE:

Here's an example using an interface:

```
public interface IMathAlgorithm
{
    double Add(double a, double b);
}

public class FooAlgorithm : IMathAlgorithm
{
    public double Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return StaticFoo.Add(a, b);
    }
}

public class BarAlgorithm : IMathAlgorithm
{
    public double Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return StaticBar.Add(a, b);
    }
}
```

Now the consumers will always work with the `IMathAlgorithm` interface because all they care about is adding two numbers and not the way this adding is implemented. The factory pattern could ease the creation of a specific implementation of a given algorithm but [DI frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) do this job just fine.

Now if you have some ugly legacy code that you don't have control over and which depends on static classes/methods you could invoke it in the specific implementation of a given algorithm. The advantage is that it is now hidden behind the specific implementation and the consumers of the algorithm don't have to call/rely on it explicitly.

Comment: Sample code of what? I don't even know what your classes look like currently. If you don't know how to use an interface or base class I would recommend you starting with some tutorials on OOP. Here's an example of the [Factory Pattern in C#](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx).

Comment: I know about Factory but I can't see how to use them within the context of my problem since Factory by itself has nothing to do with the interface implementation problem.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the factory has nothing to do with the interface implementation problem. The factory could be used by the consumers of those algorithms.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for examples the wrap the static logic inside an instance. Do exactly what Darin recommends by wrapping the static calls inside an instance abstracted by the interface, like so:
   public class InstanceAlgorithm : IMathAlgorithm
   {
      public double Add(double a, double b)
      {
         return StaticClass.StaticAdd(a, b);
      }
   }

Answer (score 1):

Just make your class non-static and implement your interface. Factory is about encapsulating your concrete class inside the factory and provide only the instance of the interface to the outside, which appropriates for your situation but not mandatory.